# Msi Installer Runs custom Action but leaves File for Installation

Tags: c++, wix, windows-installer

I have following Wix File that is supposed to install the contents in `C:\SampleProgram` . The generated msi is supposed to be installed as `msiexec /i installer.msi IPADDRESS="1.1.1.1"`. The parameter `IPADDRESS` is fetched by Custom Action that will make a config file as below in the folder where program installs itself.

```
{
  "ip" : "1.1.1.1" 
}
```

The problem is that the generated Installation File works fine in one of my machine but it only creates a config file in other machine. The folder where the MSI installed successfully will have all the `Component` Files defined under `ComponentGroup` of my wix File. If Installed successfully, the Installer will copy all those components in Installed Folder. Even though It didn't install the files, but it ran the Custom Action.

The verbose log is given [here](http://pastebin.com/wrzYVgCD).

If one searches **Component: BoostThreadLibrary** , I get  **Installed: Absent**, which as given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that **Component or feature is not currently installed.**.

Is the error related to my machine or this code.

I have attached wix file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="SampleProgram" Language="1033" Version="3.0.0" Manufacturer="Learning" UpgradeCode="a0265d05-8e65-4af2-98e1-a675b728dd2d">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SampleProgram" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="WindowsVolume">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SampleProgram" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="ProductComponent">
        <File
          Id="LPAEXE"
          Name="lpa.exe"
          DiskId="1"
          Source="$(var.lpa.TargetPath)"
          Vital="yes"
          KeyPath="yes" />

        <?if $(var.Configuration) = "Release"?>
          <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes"
                          Name="LearningService" DisplayName="LearningService"
                          Description="How to make a Service" Start="auto"
                          Account="LocalSystem" ErrorControl="normal" Interactive="no" />

          <ServiceControl Id="StartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall"
                          Name="LearningService" Wait="yes" />
        <?endif?>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="BoostThreadLibrary">
        <?if $(var.Configuration) = "Debug"?>
        <File Source ="C:\boost_1_55_0_dyn\stage\lib\boost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.dll" />
        <?else?>
        <File Source ="C:\boost_1_55_0_dyn\stage\lib\boost_thread-vc100-mt-1_55.dll" />
        <?endif?>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="BoostSystemLibrary">
        <?if $(var.Configuration) = "Debug"?>
        <File Source ="C:\boost_1_55_0_dyn\stage\lib\boost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.dll" />
        <?else?>
        <File Source ="C:\boost_1_55_0_dyn\stage\lib\boost_system-vc100-mt-1_55.dll" />
        <?endif?>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="BoostChronoLibrary">
        <?if $(var.Configuration) = "Debug"?>
        <File Source ="C:\boost_1_55_0_dyn\stage\lib\boost_chrono-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.dll" />
        <?else?>
        <File Source ="C:\boost_1_55_0_dyn\stage\lib\boost_chrono-vc100-mt-1_55.dll" />
        <?endif?>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="BoostFileSystemLibrary">
        <?if $(var.Configuration) = "Debug"?>
        <File Source ="C:\boost_1_55_0_dyn\stage\lib\boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.dll" />
        <?else?>
        <File Source ="C:\boost_1_55_0_dyn\stage\lib\boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_55.dll" />
        <?endif?>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="BoostDateTimeLibrary">
        <?if $(var.Configuration) = "Debug"?>
        <File Source ="C:\boost_1_55_0_dyn\stage\lib\boost_date_time-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.dll" />
        <?else?>
        <File Source ="C:\boost_1_55_0_dyn\stage\lib\boost_date_time-vc100-mt-1_55.dll" />
        <?endif?>
      </Component>

      <Component Id="BoostZlibLibrary">
        <?if $(var.Configuration) = "Debug"?>
        <File Source ="C:\boost_1_55_0_dyn\stage\lib\boost_zlib-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.dll" />
        <?else?>
        <File Source ="C:\boost_1_55_0_dyn\stage\lib\boost_zlib-vc100-mt-1_55.dll" />
        <?endif?>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="BoostIOStreamLibrary">
        <?if $(var.Configuration) = "Debug"?>
        <File Source ="C:\boost_1_55_0_dyn\stage\lib\boost_iostreams-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.dll" />
        <?else?>
        <File Source ="C:\boost_1_55_0_dyn\stage\lib\boost_iostreams-vc100-mt-1_55.dll" />
        <?endif?>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="BoostRegexLibrary">
        <?if $(var.Configuration) = "Debug"?>
        <File Source ="C:\boost_1_55_0_dyn\stage\lib\boost_regex-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.dll" />
        <?else?>
        <File Source ="C:\boost_1_55_0_dyn\stage\lib\boost_regex-vc100-mt-1_55.dll" />
        <?endif?>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="libeay32">
        <File Source ="C:\OpenSSL-Win32\libeay32.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="ssleay32">
        <File Source ="C:\OpenSSL-Win32\ssleay32.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="czmq">
        <?if $(var.Configuration) = "Debug"?>
        <File Source ="..\..\ext_library\zmq\czmq\czmq-2.1.0\lib\Win32\DebugDLL\czmq.dll" />
        <?else?>
        <File Source ="..\..\ext_library\zmq\czmq\czmq-2.1.0\lib\Win32\ReleaseDLL\czmq.dll" />
        <?endif?>
      </Component>

      <Component Id="log4cplus">
        <?if $(var.Configuration) = "Debug"?>
        <File Source ="..\..\ext_library\log4cplus\bin\Debug\log4cplusD.dll" />
        <?else?>
        <File Source ="..\..\ext_library\log4cplus\bin\Release\log4cplus.dll" />
        <?endif?>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="libzmq">
        <?if $(var.Configuration) = "Debug"?>
        <File Source ="..\..\ext_library\zmq\zeromq-4.0.3\lib\Win32\Debug\libzmq.dll" />
        <?else?>
        <File Source ="..\..\ext_library\zmq\zeromq-4.0.3\lib\Win32\Release\libzmq.dll" />
        <?endif?>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="SSL_Crt_File">
        <File Source ="..\..\src\keys\ca.crt" />
      </Component>

    </ComponentGroup>    
    <Binary Id="SetupCA"  SourceFile="..\..\ext_library\SetupCA\SetupCA\bin\Release\SetupCA.CA.dll"/>
    <CustomAction Id="WRITEFILETODISK" Execute="immediate" BinaryKey="SetupCA" DllEntry="WriteFileToDisk" />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="WRITEFILETODISK" Sequence="2"></Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but changing the `upgrade code` to other `GUID` did solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The core of your problem is the scheduling of your custom action:

```
<CustomAction Id="WRITEFILETODISK" Execute="immediate" BinaryKey="SetupCA" DllEntry="WriteFileToDisk" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="WRITEFILETODISK" Sequence="2"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

As an immediate action scheduled before `InstallFinalize`, any changes to files will not have occurred by the time this custom action is run. While that can be important for, say, an uninstallation, this is probably the opposite of what you want for an installation.

To read files that are installed by your installation, you should schedule your action `Execute="deferred"`, and sometime after `InstallFiles`. If you are modifying items in a system location, it should also be `Impersonate="No"`, which only works in the deferred execution context.

Note that once your action is deferred, you will have to access properties through `CustomActionData`.

Comment: The thing is that same code works for other machine. Everything setups completely and config is created but in my machine I don't get any installed files. Instead in logs I get `Installed: Absent` for components

Comment: Thanks for pointing me the Custom Action Issue. I will modify it too.

Comment: I may have misread what you meant by "The problem is that I am unable to get the files that Wix should be copying in Installed Folder but the installer runs custom action" as so many people encounter the problem I describe. Could you instead clarify what you are expecting, and what you are encountering, and when exactly each of those happen - namely if the overall failure is that at the end no files were installed, my answer is tangential at best.

Comment: The installer generated does work in another machine where it will load all the components correctly and makes a config file. The same installer in my machine doesn't load any components I gave in `ComponentGroup` but does generate Config File. On comparing Logs of both installation, I saw `Installed: Local` for successfully installed machine but `Absent` in my machine. It just doesn't load any components written inside `ComponentGroup`. Is the issue related to my code or my machine?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "load all the components" - this sounds like terminology describing something your custom action does, not behavior expected of Windows Installer. Please edit the question to provide a clearer picture of the expected behavior, and how you are diagnosing that it doesn't occur.